# OCaml This is not a function; it cannot be applied

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a function `num_order rank -> int` defined.

the following function call will cause a error

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > (num_order r)
dom_rank Seven Eight
```

> Line 1: Error: This expression has type int
>
> ```
>   This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
> ```

it seems to be the first line to be causing the problem... however when I remove the second line, the error is gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > (num_order r)
dom_rank Seven Eight
```

is the very same thing as

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > (num_order r) dom_rank Seven Eight
```

or

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > ((num_order r) dom_rank Seven Eight)
```

because function application takes precedence over binary operators like `>`.  With this in mind, the error message of the compiler should be pretty clear.

To separate the two statements you would probably write them as

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > (num_order r);;
dom_rank Seven Eight;;
```

in the interactive toplevel, or as

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > (num_order r)
let dr78 = dom_rank Seven Eight
```

in a module definition, also giving a name to the value you compute.

The usual way to trigger a function only having a side effect is to use the idiosyncratic

```
let () = print_endline "Hello, World!"
```

Do not be confused by differences between using the OCaml interactive loop and regular programming.  In the OCaml interactive loop, it is possible to evaluate a single expression, which has the side effect of printing the resulting value.  When writing an OCaml program, evaluating expressions is an error, we should use `let` bindings instead.  In the OCaml interactive loop, the `;;` sequence can be used to separate phrases.  While this is also supported for writing regular programs, this is often regarded as a hacky construct to enhance compatibility between code for the interactive toplevel and regular program code.

The `;` is the sequence operator used to combine several expressions in one expression.  It should be not confused with `;;` which merely indicate the end of a sentence.

Comment: oh! thanks so much ! this is exactly what I am confused about :), can you explain a little bit more about the use of `;` and `;;`? :)

Comment: The `;;` is just an artefact bound to the toplevel, where it is needed to signal the end of an evaluation phrase – note that a single `;` would not. The compiler does not need this end of phrase statement because it does not need to evaluate a sentence as soon as possible and has end of file markers anyway. But `;;` is also understood by the compiler, as a convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I need to add `;;` at the end of the first line. It is also possible to write the following (I think this is more correct) :

```
let dom_rank r1 r = (num_order r1) > (num_order r)
let _ = dom_rank Seven Eight
```

Comment: Not that if OP was doing it in file.